NotEnoughBytesError: Serializer [publicKey] expected 32 bytes, got 11 when trying to get asset id
Getting the error below trying to get the asset Id when minting a compressed NFT
NotEnoughBytesError: Serializer [publicKey] expected 32 bytes, got 11.
    at Object.deserialize (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-serializers/src/publicKey.ts:41:15)
    at forEach (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-serializers/src/struct.ts:51:47)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.deserialize (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-serializers/src/struct.ts:50:14)
    at Object.deserialize (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-serializers/src/dataEnum.ts:165:50)
    at parseLeafFromMintV1Transaction (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum/src/leafAssetId.ts:40:44)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async findAssetId (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/src/bubblegum.ts:108:27)

Below is the code I am using to find the asset id
async function findAssetId() {
    const merkleTree = publicKey("mzHgYPtHWb3e6XphQuomD2KsAtJoPbzpMriK9ow3Gs7");

    const leaf: LeafSchema = await parseLeafFromMintV1Transaction(
        umi,
        base58.serialize(
            "54TgSmMMLZLTFjTHTFPvmThJ3kyV2CvBiAoro962aQNpQCCqVHtuf7baEcfYyrPZnQuifoGCMFAQkZTkchSDD2KB"
        )
    );
    console.log("asset id from leaf id", leaf.id);

    const assetId = findLeafAssetIdPda(umi, {
        merkleTree: merkleTree,
        leafIndex: leaf.nonce,
    });
    console.log("asset Id from find pda", assetId);
}

findAssetId().then().catch(console.error);


Turns out that the culprit was me passing in the wrong transaction hash.
The parseLeafFromMintV1Transaction method expects a mintV1 transaction signature while I was passing in the tx hash from the create bubblegum instruction.
